# why is a "apron on lathe" called an apron?

Tags: terminology

I am wondering about the term "apron" used for a lathe. It is a gear mechanism, it seems.

See http://images.slideplayer.com/26/8615152/slides/slide_47.jpg.

Why apron? Why does apron come in here as a term at all?

Comment: It may be that the term "apron" is used to mean cover. The mechanics are under a cover. But there may be something here not at all obvious.

Comment: Looks on slide 46 like they're referring to an enclosure that resembles an apron, and slide 47 shows the internal mechanisms under the apron? It is confusing.

Comment: Yes, Brekets; why does any such thing come in at all, pleaes?

Comment: https://www.countrysideamishfurniture.com/help/faq/what-is-an-apron ~ "Aprons" are also found on fine furniture. Even I (who is not Amish) use the term for that part of any piece of furniture. In fact, just the other day I referred to the lower section of an antique Pine trunk that had been converted for use as a blanket chest, using the very same terminology.

Comment: https://community.cartalk.com/t/aprons-what-are-the-aprons/6952 ~ "Aprons" are also found on cars, something my father would have known.

Comment: Note that "apron" is used in many domains, referring to something that "skirts" the central object.  The area adjacent to an airport runway is often called an "apron", as is the paved shoulder on the inner side of an oval racecar track.

Comment: Understand that "apron" was originally used for any skirt-like over-garment that hung from the waist.  Knights wore "aprons".

Answer (score 7):

It's called an apron because it hangs over the front side of the lathe.

First see this definition:

> Apron is attached to the carriage and hangs over the front side of the lathe bed.
>   <sub>[Apron Mechanism in Lathe](http://www.mechanicalhero.com/2015/03/apron-mechanism-in-lathe.html)</sub>

And then see this diagram:

[image]
<sub>Image source: [Vinagento.com](http://vinagento.com/apron-mechanism-in-lathe-machine/apron-mechanism-in-lathe-machine-apron-mechanism-in-lathe-machine-l-a-tension-release-mechanism-for-loosening-the-drive-belt-is-apron-mechanism-of-lathe-machine-pdf/)</sub>

The apron hangs down perpendicular to the bed of the lathe, hanging in an apron-like way.

Comment: I work for a machine shop :-)